# Gantt Chart with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, gantt-chart

http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/VkghS/

Currently sorting between rows can be done by dragging barWrap (grey). To move gantt bar can be done by dragging the bar.

What I want is sorting and moving can be done at once by dragging the bar. How to achieve this?

Any helps would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: +1 Great jsfiddle, helped me a lot.

Comment: The jsfiddle is down. Can you repost the code?

Comment: @ErnestoCampohermoso Please try again, I rolled back my JSFiddle username. Didn't notice that username changing affects the URLs, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sortable widget has a handle feature. So:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".gantt" ).sortable({
        handle: '.bar' // Make it sortable by dragging the .bar instead of the container
    });
    /*
    $( ".bar" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: '.gantt',
        containment: '.barWrap',
        grid: [20, 0]
    });
    */
    $( ".bar" ).resizable({
        handles: 'e, w',
        grid: [ 20, 0 ]
    });

    $(".gantt").disableSelection();
});
```

**Edited (see comment)**: You have to take out the draggable, which IMO isn't so bad because people can still use resizable to change the position. You could experiment with draggable handles to find a method where they both work.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't work :( The draggable and sortables must be interfering with each other. I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but you just need to add another div wrapper to achieve this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VkghS/1021/)):

```
$(function() {
    $('.barWrap').wrapInner('<div class="sorter"></div>');
    $( ".gantt" ).sortable({
        handle: '.sorter'
    });

    $( ".bar" ).resizable({
        handles: 'e, w',
        grid: [ 20, 0 ]
    });

    $(".gantt").disableSelection();
});
```